# Firebase get Authentication details using UID

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building a admin panel for a android app in javascript and php in which i created a users table with  Firebase Authentication UID so every user key is UID but in this user table i am not inserting **Auth Identifier**. now in my admin panel how can i retrieve Auth Identifier (Phone Number) using UID(user Key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get the firebase authenticated User info from the current session/user, and if you need to query for it later then you need to save it in your own datastore.

For more details, see this https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing

Comment: ok so there is otherway to get  authenticated User info using UID . that means i need to store phone number in app..but there are already users created in my app database what about them do i need to manually insert phone number in database ?

Comment: you can write a migration script or something like that for existing datastore

Comment: migration script like what ? any clues or hint

Comment: here's a nice article worth reading to get hint https://medium.com/@wcandillon/firebase-schema-evolution-ea830a62c14e

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to storing the data in the database (as Qasim answered) is to use the Firebase Admin SDK to look up the user's profile by its UID.

The Firebase Admin SDK runs with administrative privileges, and thus can perform certain sensitive operations that the regular client-side SDKs are not allowed to do. As such, it is meant to be only run in trusted environments, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions for Firebase. With these last two you could create your own API, that your admin panel then calls. Just be sure to [secure the API](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/authorized-https-endpoint), because otherwise you're leaking user information.