# How to get FirebaseUser from a uid?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Let's say I've a user id

```
String uid = "1234abcdefgh890";
```

Now, I'd want to get a `FirebaseUser` using this uid, how do I do that?

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
FirebaseUser user = (await auth.signInWithXXX(uid)).user; // is there any method like this
```

How can I get the `FirebaseUser` then?

Comment: Is this helpfull? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889729/how-to-get-the-user-email-in-firebase-based-on-user-id/49002292

Comment: Thanks but it wasn't quite useful.

Comment: Not sure if you can get a FirebaseUser, But a little hack you can use, is to Create a User model (class) with a factory function that takes a DocumentSnapshot and returns a User instance. So all you have to do is query a document with a given id. and with the returend DocumentSnapshot you can create a User.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API in the Firebase client-side SDKs to get user information based on a UID, as this could potentially be a security concern.

If you need this information, you can either implement your own server that uses the Firebase Admin SDKs (which **do** have this functionality), or you can store user information in a secondary database, such as Firebase's own Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore. Then you can query this database from the rest of your application, and secure access to fit your needs with the database's server-side security rules.

Also see:

- [How do I return a list of users if I use the Firebase simple username & password authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password)
- [Firebase get user by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39542945/firebase-get-user-by-id)
- [How to get the user email in Firebase based on user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889729/how-to-get-the-user-email-in-firebase-based-on-user-id)
- [Using Firebase User UID to retrieve profile info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51067180/using-firebase-user-uid-to-retrieve-profile-info)
- [Firebase get Authentication details using UID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51943394/firebase-get-authentication-details-using-uid)